# Inflation in degrees $0$, $-1$, and $-2$ for Tate cohomology of finite groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Let $\pi\colon G'\to G$ be a surjective homomorphism of finite groups, and let $A$ be a $G$-module.
I need explicit formulas for the inflation maps
$${\rm Inf}^{r}\colon H^{r}(G,A)\to H^{r}(G',A)$$ for $r=0,-1,-2$.
In this post, by $H^r(G,A)$ I mean the *modified* (Tate) cohomology in degree $r$.

I recall the definitions of $H^{-1}$, $H^0$, and $H^1$. Let
$$A^G=\{a\in A\mid g\cdot a=a\ \,\forall g\in G\}$$
denote the subgroup of $G$-invariants, and
$$A_G=A\,/\langle g\cdot a-a\mid g\in G,\, a\in A\rangle$$
denote the group $G$-coinvariants.
Consider the map
$$N\colon A\to A, \quad a\mapsto \sum_{g\in G} g\cdot a.$$
This map $N$ factors through a map
$$N_*\colon A_G\to A^G.$$
We set
$$ H^{-1}(G,A)=\ker N_*\,,\quad H^0(G,A)={\rm coker\,} N_*\,.$$
Moreover,
$$H^1(G,A)=Z^1(G,A)/B^1(G,A),$$
where
\begin{align*}
&Z^1(G,A)=\big\{z\colon G\to A\,\mid\, z(g_1g_2)=z(g_1) +g_1\cdot z(g_2)\big\}\\
&B^1(G,A)=\{g\mapsto g\cdot a -a \,\mid\, a\in A\}\subseteq Z^1(G,A).
\end{align*}

The inflation map on 1-cocycles is defined  by
$$ z\mapsto z\circ\pi\colon\, Z^1(G,A)\to Z^1(G',A).$$
This map induces the inflation map on $H^1$.
The inflation maps on $H^r$ for $r<1$ are defined using dimension shifting.
I understand that it is just an exercise to compute ${\rm Inf}^r$, but I struggle with this exercise!

> **Question 1.** Is it true that the inflation map  ${\rm Inf}^{-1}$ fits into the following commutative diagram:
> $\require{AMScd}$
> \begin{CD}
> H^{-1}(G,A) @>{\rm Inf}^{-1}>>   H^{-1}(G',A)\\
> @VVV                          @VVV \\
> A_G          @=                A_{G'} 
> \end{CD}

> **Question 2.** How can one explicitly describe the inflation map ${\rm Inf}^0$?

> **Question 3.** How can one explicitly describe the group $H^{-2}(G,A)=H_1(G,A)$
> and the inflation map ${\rm Inf}^{-2}$  in terms of (nonhomogeneous) cocycles?